# How to remove n last items in a filtered crossfilter data

Tags: javascript, crossfilter

I'm using [crossfilter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crossfilter2) just to filter a JSON array.
What I need to do is:

- After filtering, remove `n` last items in the array so that the array has the `length` of `50` if the filtered array is larger than `50` in `length`

The current code is:

```
    const re = new RegExp('example', 'gimu');

    const commentData = crossfilter(exampleComments);
    return commentData
      .dimension(c => c.comment)
      .filter(comment => re.test(comment))
      .allFiltered();
```

What do I need to do after `.allFiltered()` to slice the array so that the length of the returned data is `50`?

I could easily achieve this with vanilla Javascript but I would prefer to use [crossfilter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crossfilter2).

Comment: Can you provide a sample of input and expected output?

Comment: @adiga Data doesn't matter, I just want to remove last n items from the array using crossfilter. Thanks

Comment: `.allFiltered().slice(0 , 50)` ?

Comment: If you need to feed this to a chart so that it updates dynamically, you could use a [fake group](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#fake-groups). Doesn't sound like you do, and @adiga's snippet should be all you need...